# Escaping correctly QUOTE characters in SQL query

Tags: mysql, database, escaping

I've a column in my MySql database with values like this

```
firstname + ',' + surname
```

the character ' is part of the content.

I've to make a query to db like this:

```
SELECT * FROM UDERSCHEMA where EXPRESSION like 'firstname +  '','' + surname'
```

as you can see I tried to escape ' quoting it (with another '), but when I make the query on db result is empty set, I've to retrieve instead a set with one entry, how can I modify my query to correctly make MySql understand special characters as ' ?

Comment: Can you provide a SQLFiddle example of your data? I'm confused whether the first "sample data" is an expression you use in your SQL or if that is the actual data inside a single column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Escape special characters with a back-slash](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html).

Answer:

```
\'
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4592/3)

Comment: [What seems to be the problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4592/1)? Is it because I did not mention that quotes and double-quotes can be doubled, as a special case?

Comment: @RandomSeed: doubling the single quotes is not a "special" case. That's what the SQL standard defines for "escaping". The usage of the backslash is a non-standard extension in MySQL.